# NUL characters sometimes appear next to ASCII characters in a concatenation of multiple text files

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file, `output.txt`, that is a concatenation of 1k other files, created via a python script.

```python
import shutil

with open('output_file.txt','wb') as wfd:
    for f in file_paths:
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
            wfd.write(b"\n")
```

When I open it in Notepad++, I see

[image]

When I open it in Notepad, I see

[image]

which corresponds to the same place.

To make it more confusing, other parts of the file in Notepad++ are read correct:

[image]

Any possible reason why Notepad++ does not read the characters correct in some parts of the file and not others?

Here is how the text is viewed in Notepad++

[image]

and what I see in Notepad

[image]

Comment: Notepad doesn't show invisible characters, Notepad++ does (if you tell him to do so). Are the orginal files showing the same?

Comment: updated question, but looking closer, it appears what you mention is true. Do you know how to remove the `NULL` in Notepad++?

Comment: Looks like UTF-16/extended ASCII encoding confusion. Check the encoding of the source file (especially check the presence of the BOM), and encoding settings in both editors.

Comment: Hypothesis: some of your files are in UTF-8 and some of them are in UTF-16. Concatenating them as binary streams without encoding conversion creates a file with an incoherent encoding that the editors don’t know how to handle.